# Jquery How to refresh several comments like Facebook without putting too much load on the server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have developed a comment system like Facebook where my users comment under the post of others or under their own post using jquery and php. However when there is a new comment, i launch an Ajax request to load the newest comment and replace the oldest one.

**Problem**

When i have about 100 post and each of them has a comment it means that 100 request will be launch to the server in order to refresh the comment AND That is not good at all for the server.

**Question**

Is there another way of updating several comments at once, with one request or is there a way of updating only the comment that are where the screen is and it it will only update when the user scrolls down ?

Thanks

Comment: What so far you have tried....

Comment: try use `setInterval`

Comment: @tonoslfx Yes I am already using set interval but this implies that i will launch 100 or 1000 queries every x minutes. Which is still much load.

Comment: @user3454479 so far i have used setInterval to launch a function that loads and add the latest messages however this method to me seems to put a lot of load on the server

Comment: you can paginate and show the latest 10 messages only. then put a button "click for more" below the messages. when they click the button, then show another 10 with ajax calls

Comment: @tonoslfx Yes I have done that. However, still, if i have 10 Messages and each one of them has 100 comments I will have to push 10 ajax request to the server. Is there no way to push only one request and update all the comments under the 10 messages based on what you just suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

You can react to users showing comments and then send request to load new data. jQuery can react to [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event, or maybe you can use focus of element. With [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) you can find if element is on screen. Or maybe mouseover event. You can combine these methods, also try to use setInterval as tonoslfx suggested.

If you are going to use scroll or mouseover events, remember they are fired pretty often. With these is good idea to implement some kind of request lock, like this:

- mouseover event find out comment should be refreshed
- request is launched to server
- flag inside the element is set to working
- cursor is still above comment, so mouseover fires again, checks the flag and abort sending new request to server

Since mouseover and scroll events fires multiple per second, this is necessary. I personally store these flags inside [.data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) property of DOM tree element